# Uncertainity with CIPSEND command to updating the data field on thingspeak using esp8266

Tags: esp8266, at-commands

I am having a bit of uncertainty here updating data on thingspeak using their generated API or may be because of the "AT+CIPSEND" command. Below are steps I followed for the 1st trial:

```
AT+RST


OK
B1���:6�;�;!G��R��A#�
[System Ready, Vendor:www.ai-thinker.com]
AT+CWMODE?

+CWMODE:1

OK
AT+CIPMUX=1


OK
AT+CIPSTART=0,"TCP","api.thingspeak.com",80


OK
Linked
AT+CIPSEND=0,85

> GET https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=1VMOGPWM9SGJXI5C&field1=77


OK
Unlink
```

I have been following Kevin Darrah's tutorial [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qU76yWHeQuw). When tried the above, the data field does not update.So, 1st trial failed!!!.

But, when I did the below by changing the length of bytes assigned to CIPSEND command with 76, surprisingly the data was updated on thingspeak.

```
AT+RST


 OK
 �6B�=Cl��1�� �A#�+�A��
 [System Ready, Vendor:www.ai-thinker.com]
 AT+CWMODE?

+CWMODE:1

OK
AT+CIPMUX=1


OK
AT+CIPSTART=4,"TCP","api.thingspeak.com",80


OK
Linked
AT+CIPSEND=4,76

> GET https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=U6PE1HI433A8XPQY&field1=77


SEND OK

+IPD,4,1:1
OK

OK
Unlink
```

So, the 2nd trial worked!!!.

Again, I did a third trial and this time I changed the length of bytes assigned to the CIPSEND command to 100 as shown below:

```
 AT+CIPSTART=4,"TCP","api.thingspeak.com",80


 OK
 Linked
 AT+CIPSEND=4,100

> GET https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=U6PE1HI433A8XPQY&field1=46


OK
Unlink
```

The only difference between the 3 trials is the length of bytes to send, assigned using "AT+CIPSEND". And the data is posted to thingspeak successfully only when the length of bytes is assigned as **76**, but did not work when assigned with 85 and 100.I am using Arduino IDE's serial monitor to send these commands with NL&CR enabled.My question is,

***Why is it working when CIPSEND is assigned with value of 76 and not for 85 and 100***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the length of your data:

```
GET https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=U6PE1HI433A8XPQY&field1=46
```

is 72 characters, plus `\r\n\r\n` makes exactly 76 characters. I guess if you specify a longer length in `CIPSEND` it is expecting more data, and you are being disconnected due to a timeout or something.